# Possibility of having a spacetime trajectory that cuts the $t=$constant at more than one point

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, causality, time-travel

Can we have a spacetime trajectory like the blue curve (shown in the figure) inside the lightcone such that the trajectory cuts a $t={\rm constant}$ line at more than one point (three points in the figure)?

[image]

Since such a curve is entirely inside the lightcone, I don't see why such a curve should be forbidden.

(Sorry for the poorly drawn diagram. Hope it is understandable. This figure is inspired from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYoXCo7mXG8&t=1406s) at $21.11$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lightcone should be defined at each point, not just the origin. So the curve leaves the lightcone (when the angle is less than 45 degrees). The points on the redline are spacelike separated, so they can't be causally linked.

Comment: One can draw the curve in such a way that it remains within the lightcone at each spacetime point but still show this feature.

Comment: Draw a lightcone at *every point* along the curve. The curve will not stay within its forward light cone.

Comment: I'm not sure what it even means for a spacetime coordinate to be a multivalued function in this sense. Are we talking about special relativity on flat spacetime, in which case the lightcones in your diagram are always 45 degrees in these coordinates (implying the trajectory change from timelike to null to spacelike, which isn't allowed)? Or are we talking about some nontrivial curved non-time orientable spacetime where the lightcones are tilted giving closed timelike curves? Either way the question doesn't seem well defined, and the curve shouldn't be allowed in normal circumstances.

Comment: I am talking about special relativity and flat spacetime. Assume a light cone at each point where the trajectory turns around. Now, at the turning point, bend the trajectory in such a way that it remains either within the past light cone or future light cone. What is the problem with such a zigzag path?

Comment: Draw a lightcone at each point: you will see the curve **does not** stay within its lightcone. That is the problem.

Comment: Start walking in one direction (e.g. north) and attempt to get back to where you started without ever exceeding an angle of of 45 degrees (from north)...

Comment: Wait I think I see your confusion: a trajectory cannot travel 'forward' within its past light cone. That involves travelling backwards in time. Remember that travelling directly upwards on the diagram (y-direction) involves not moving at all: you have no choice but to move forwards into your future light cone.

Comment: See the right panel diagram at 19.50 minutes here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYoXCo7mXG8&t=1406s

Comment: Yes, the right diagram has the y-axis as y, a *spatial* coordinate. Padmanabhan even *explicitly says* in that exact video (a few seconds before): in space, a path can can go back on itself, but it **cannot do it in time**. I.e. for a spacetime diagram with t on the y-axis, this **cannot** happen.

Comment: Sorry. You should see the figure at 21.11. $y$-axis is time $t$, not y. His whole point is that in spacetime diagram the particle can have this weird feature. What you say is true only for the proper time, according to Padmanabhan

Comment: In special relativity, it can't. A particle cannot follow that path in special relativity or general relativity. The videos is about quantum gravity. He explicitly says in this case a particle is going forwards and backwards in time, which he then says is actually like having multiple particles.

Comment: This is the last thing I'll say: Padmanabhan knows a lot about relativity, but those lectures are about quantum field theory. He is showing how relativistic quantum mechanics breaks down and why we need to move to fields instead. A massive particle *should not* be observed outside it's forward light-cone. If you try and use relativity and (single-particle) quantum mechanics, you get contradictions where this does happen. Hence the need for QFT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116749/discussion-between-eletie-and-mithusengupta123).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see why such a curve should be forbidden

Such a curve would exceed the speed of light at several parts of the curve. It is therefore not a possible curve for a massive particle.

Comment: Dear @Dale Please see the picture around 22.00 minutes of the video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYoXCo7mXG8&t=3192s